# Free space vector Helmholtz equation with spherically symmetric source

Tags: vector-analysis, wave-equation, laplacian, greens-function

I have issues or confusions to solve the vector Helmholtz equation in free space for a spherically symmetric source. Let the equation:

$$ \left( \widehat{\Delta} + k^2 \right) \boldsymbol{a} = f(r) \boldsymbol{e_r}$$

with $k$ positive wave vector, $\widehat{\Delta}$ vector Laplacian, $r$ spherical radius, $f(r)$ a function (with $\int_0^{\infty} r^n f(r) d r < + \infty$ for integers $n$, for instance $f \propto e^{- \alpha r}$ with $\alpha >0$ is a perfect candidate), $\boldsymbol{a}$ the unknown and $\boldsymbol{e_r}$ the unit radial vector.

How to solve it just for free space ? In far field approximation it is largely good enough.

**What I tried**

Because the source is radial, I assume the field $\boldsymbol{a}$ should be radial: $ \boldsymbol{a}= a(r) \boldsymbol{e_r}$. Then I have (I checked my mistake in [del formula article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Del_in_cylindrical_and_spherical_coordinates#Del_formula)):

$$ \left( \Delta_r - 2/r^2 + k^2 \right) a(r) = f(r)  $$

Then I was thinking using the Green's function of Helmholtz equation but it is not a scalar Helmholtz equation... Thanks for reading.

**Hint**

This last equation can be rewrite in:

$$ \left( u^2 \partial_u^2 + 2 u \partial_u - 2 + u^2 \right) a(u) = u^2 f(u)  $$

with $u = k r$, is an inhomogeneous [spherical Bessel differential equation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalBesselDifferentialEquation.html) of order $1$ ($n = 1$ in the link). We can add boundary conditions (it is even better than free space for my problem):
$$a(0) = 0$$ $$a(+ \infty) \rightarrow 0$$ With these B.C, it is maybe possible to try an [eigenvalue decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%27s_function#Eigenvalue_expansions) on [spherical Bessel function of first kind](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalBesselFunctionoftheFirstKind.html) (they are nul on $0$ for order $> 0$) on an order to define. Trying this I found (using Sturm-Liouvile and eigenvalue decomposition of Green function):

$$ a(r) = 1/k^2 \sum_{n=2}^{+ \infty} \int_0^{+ \infty} u'^2 f(u')\frac{j_n(u') j_n(k r)}{N_n \left[2 - n(n+1) \right]} d u' $$

with $N_n = \int_0^{+ \infty} j_n(u')^2 d u'$, $j_n(u)$ being the spherical Bessel function of first kind and order $n$. The issue is that the sum is incomplete (I miss the term $0$ and $1$), so I do not know if the Green function decomposition is still valid.